# Subversion mirror with GIT

Tags: git, svn, repository, subgit

I have a Apache Subversion Repository in the internet, which I'd like to mirror into my (tbd) local network repository.

I will develop my changes locally and commit them into my local network repository, which is held up to date with the repository in the internet ("mirror") by a e.g. cronjob.

As I'd like to use GIT in my local network, I need a solution to solve this synchronisation "problem".

Is SubGit the right solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ss it clearly and definitely states [SubGit Remote Book](http://subgit.com/book-remote/index.html)